# How to assign a variable to an output in Python?

Tags: python

I have a coding assignment where we are supposed to find the difference between two timestamps. I have completed the code for that however it is supposed to print as "x hour(s) y minute(s) z second(s)".

I tried using
`print('hours" + (x), 'minutes' + (y), 'seconds' + (z)`
but it is not working.

`x = int(((a-b) // 3600))
y = int(((a-b) % 3600) // 60)
z = int((a-b) % 60 )`

this is the code I am using.

Comment: You'll want to look into [string formatting](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting).

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using python 3.*

```
a = 1
b = 2

x = int(((a-b) // 3600))
y = int(((a-b) % 3600) // 60)
z = int((a-b) % 60 )

print(f'hours {x} minutes {y} seconds {z}')
```

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense to only do the subtraction and the integer conversion once.

```
from datetime import datetime

a = datetime.now().timestamp()
b = datetime(2019,9,1).timestamp()

c = int(a - b)

hh = c // 3600
mm = c % 3600 // 60
ss = c % 60

print(f"hours: {hh}, minutes: {mm}, seconds: {ss}")
```

Result

```
hours: 213, minutes: 10, seconds: 27
```